# Why Expression.Call is throwing parameters error

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, expression

I'm trying to extract Count method, so I could reuse it later to build expression tree.

```
var g = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<float?>), "g");
var countMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods()
    .Single(m => m.Name == "Count" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 1);
var countMaterialized = countMethod
    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { g.Type });
var expr = Expression.Call(countMaterialized, g);
```

It throws this error:

System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Single]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Single]]]' of method 'Int32 Count[IEnumerable1](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Single]]])''

What am I missing?

Comment: The type parameter for the generic should be `float?`, not `IEnumerable<float?>`. Guess which `g.Type` is returning?

Comment: If you look at the declaration for `Enumerable.Count<TSource>` you will see that `TSource` is not the `IEnumerable<T>` but just the item types in the `IEnumerable` so change the `MakeGenericMethod` to use `typeof(float)` instead of `g.Type`.

Comment: after putting typeof(float?) in MakeGenericMethod it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter type is correct, but your generic type should be "float?" instead of "IEnumerable".

```
var g = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<float?>), "g");

// get the method definition using object as a placeholder parameter
var countMethodOfObject = ((Func<IEnumerable<object>, int>)Enumerable.Count<object>).Method;

// get the generic method definition
var countMethod = countMethodOfObject.GetGenericMethodDefinition();

// create generic method
var countMaterialized = countMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(float?) });

// creare expression
var countExpression = Expression.Call(countMaterialized, g);

var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<float?>, int>>(countExpression, g);

IEnumerable<float?> floats = Enumerable.Range(3, 5).Select(v => (float?)v);
var count = expression.Compile().Invoke(floats);
```